# regex and sed in delete all characters before two delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have lines like this:

```
Sun Apr 19 13:02:34 2020 us=73808 pinco.pallino/256.62.258.116:11941 [pinco.pallino] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
```

Can I use sed, or another program, to delete all characters between a `/` and the next space (in this case `pinco.pallino`)?
I've tried more regex combinations but I've not found the correct one!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you expect from this input. Your description isn't very clear.

Comment: @ankx7 can you share the output you are expecting ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace a slash and everything following, that is not a space with empty replacement:

```
sed 's+/[^ ]*++g'
```